# What are differences of "How does Google Work?" and "How Google Works?"

Tags: questions

If I want to ask someone that how Google company's structure is working together, which sentence is correct?

Comment: I didn't think about the company structure when I looked at your question. I thought about the mechanism that Google uses to search, using algorithms such as tf-idf and a web crawler.

Comment: If one is surprised at the way Google works, one may ask, How Google works! The same can hold good while reporting a present tense. "He always talks about how Google works."  If the question is to know about 'How Google works' in its entirety, I am afraid, it is too abrupt a question to get the company's structure as a reply.  If it is a direct question, we should use "How does Google work?"

Comment: "How Google works" is not a proper question, but rather a noun phrase referring to the content of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stick to grammar, a) 'How does Google work ?' is an interrogative sentence, and b) 'How Google works', is rather a dependant clause  and part of another sentence and cannot use question mark on its own. However as intonation can suitably modulate our speech, with suitable punctuation marks it can be an exclamatory or interrogative sentence (strict grammatical structure not adhered to)

- How Google works?(!)

A questioning sentence by itself requires inversion of auxiliaries, modals or "Be" verbs be it principal or helping. However when WH-words are subjects themselves, they take verbs after them in questions.